# Javascript/JQuery not working in my Rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've been trying for so long, this is the issue:

I've got a View with a text box, and all I'm trying to do in order to check if my JQuery is working, is to display an alert message when the value of that textbox is longer than 0.
This is what I got at the moment:

**`registers/registration.html.erb`**

```
<script>
    $('input[name="Card_ID"]').keyup(function(){
        if (this.value.length > 0) {
            alert("TEST");}
    });
</script>

<table border="1">
  <%= text_field_tag 'Card_ID',nil,  :autofocus => true %>
  <tr><td>Present</td>
    <td>University ID</td>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td>Last Name</td>
    <td>Time of Arrival</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <% @studentregister.each do |t| %>
<%= simple_form_for t do |streg| %>
      <td><div class="present"><%= streg.check_box :present, :onChange => "submit()"%></div>
        <%= streg.submit :style => 'display: none' %></td>
            <td><%= streg.label Student.find(t.student_id).university_id %></td>
            <td><%= streg.label Student.find(t.student_id).first_name %></td>
            <td><%= streg.label Student.find(t.student_id).last_name %></td>
            <% if t.time_of_arrival %>
            <td><%= streg.label t.time_of_arrival.strftime('%H:%M:%S%P')%></td>
                <% else %>
            <td><%= streg.label " "%></td>
                <% end %>
             </tr>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

For testing purposes, I have also put the same code (In CoffeeScript), into the relevant `JS.COFFEE` file to see if it works:

**`registers.js.coffee`**

```
$("input[type=text]").keyup ->
  alert "TEST"  if @value.length > 0
```

But no, it still doesn't work. It's only this code that doesn't work, because when I tried to display an `alert "Test"` or `alert("Test")` when the page loads, it works.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Added some HTML source code to show what it looks like, and to see the HTML elements:

```
  <div id="main" role="main">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
           <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">

              <script>
    $('input[name="Card_ID"]').keyup(function(){
        if (this.value.length > 0) {
            alert("TEST");}
    });
</script>

<table border="1">
  <input autofocus="autofocus" id="Card_ID" name="Card_ID" type="text" />
      <tr><td>Present</td>
        <td>University ID</td>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Last Name</td>
        <td>Time of Arrival</td>
      </tr>
  <tr>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/student_registers/9" class="simple_form edit_student_register" id="edit_student_register_9" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
<div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" />
<input name="authenticity_token"   type="hidden" value="c8B0JGs4ZLVILa4a4r4PJJrD/zFcLCDhTLscBKHbFeE=" /></div>
      <td><div class="present">
<input name="student_register[present]" type="hidden" value="0" />
<input checked="checked" id="student_register_present" name="student_register[present]" onChange="submit()" type="checkbox" value="1" /></div>
        <input name="commit" style="display: none" type="submit" value="Update Student register" /></td>
            <td><label class="string optional control-label" for="student_register_w122344112">W122344112</label></td>
            <td><label class="string optional control-label" for="student_register_Daniel">Daniel</label></td>
            <td><label class="string optional control-label" for="student_register_Smith">Smith</label></td>
            <td><label class="string optional control-label" for="student_register_ "> </label></td>
             </tr>
```

Comment: Do you have an error message in your JavaScript console?  Also... did you mean for the "Card_ID"`<input>` to be outside of the `<form>` tags?

Comment: Hey, I'm not too sure how to use the JavaScript console, so I wouldn't  be able to tell you if I got an error. The reason why I put the `<input>` outside the `<form>` is because if I have it within the `form`, it will duplicate itself as it's within the `<% @studentregister.each do |t| %>` loop as well

Comment: If you open up the JavaScript console in whatever web browser you are using you can then hopefully get an error message of whatever is happening with your app.  Then, if you post the error message on your question, someone might be able to help!

Comment: Hey,had a look, but no error message appears to come up. Literally nothing appears

Comment: I guess I'm not quite sure what you are wanting to do with this type of functionality: you are wanting something to happen once someone starts typing something in the input box, right?  I made a jsfiddle for this earlier... and it seems to work on the jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/vVUpB/

Comment: I know, that's exactly the same thing I done on my jsFiddle, but when I transport that same code to my Rails applicaiton, it just doesn't work at all

Comment: I wonder if it might have to do with the [`ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function in jQuery.  You might want to consider putting your JavaScript code inside: `$(function() { ... });` so that your JavaScript can find those `input` tags.

Comment: nope, still not working ;-(
EDIT: I take it back, IT WORKS :D Thanks.

When doing it in CoffeeScript, the code should start with: 

`$ ->`

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Mind if I post that comment as an answer?

Comment: Go ahead, you deserve the rep ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a job for the jQuery [`ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function.  Try putting the JavaScript (from your code above) inside the following line of code `$(function() { ... });`

*Like this:*

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name="Card_ID"]').keyup(function(){
        if (this.value.length > 0) {
            alert("TEST");
        }
    });
});
```

By doing this, the jQuery `ready()` function *(at the very least)* gives the DOM the chance to get loaded and ready before running (or preparing to use) the JavaScript on your page.